# Angular2 show element on change of selection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Using Angular 2 typescript.  I only want to show my save button if a new option was selected. Then I want to hide the Save button after it was clicked.  How can I do that? Not really sure how to approach this. Code below:

HTML

```
<select>
   <option *ngFor="let option of optionArray" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>

<span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-primary save-button" type="submit">Save</button>
</span>
```

Comment: You can use *ngIf directive to show or hide that button. Another way, You can also write function to toggle save button on selection of any option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put ngModel on `select` field & based on select value you can show/hide submit button.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
   <option *ngFor="let option of optionArray" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>

<span class="input-group-btn" *ngIf="selectedValue">
   <button class="btn btn-primary save-button" type="submit">Save</button>
</span>
```

> **Note:** You have to import and include `FormsModule` inside your AppModule `NgModule`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *ngIf in this scenario,

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected">
   <option *ngFor="let option of optionArray" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
<span *ngIf="selected" class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary save-button" type="submit">Save</button>
</span>
```

Comment: No idea why you were downvoted, but it does look like a carbon copy of the accepted answer, with a minor change... I wonder if that was the reason

Comment: @Xander i posted at the same time

Comment: ahh yes that'll be it!